# Check if numbers summed in array match input parameter

Tags: ruby

I'm following Ruby practice problem from a website and I'm completely stuck on figuring out a solution to this problem.  Basically, given a function `has_sum?(val, arr)`, return true if **any** combination of numbers in the array (second parameter) can be added together to equal the first parameter, otherwise return false.  So:

`has_sum?(5, [1, 2, 3, 4]) # true`

`has_sum?(5, [1, 2, 6]) # false`

I'm completely stuck and not quite sure how to accomplish this...  Here's what I have so far.

```
def has_sum?(val, arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |idx, v|
    # ??? no idea what to do here except add the current num to the next in the list
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: There's no mention of that, but it'd certainly be interesting to see!

Comment: I was wrong. My answer does not require that all elements be non-negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array can produce a sum when there is a subset of any length that adds up to that sum:

```
def has_sum?(val, arr)
  (arr.size + 1).times
    .flat_map { |i| arr.combination(i).to_a }
    .any? { |s| s.inject(:+) == val }
end

has_sum?(5, [5])
# => true
has_sum?(5, [1, 2, 3])
# => true
has_sum?(5, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
# => true
has_sum?(5, [1, 2, 7])
# => false
```

This is not very efficient as it generates all the possibilities before testing. This should terminate sooner:

```
def has_sum?(val, arr)
  (arr.size + 1).times.any? { |i|
    arr.combination(i).any? { |s| s.inject(:+) == val }
  }
end
```

Even more efficiently, a recursive implementation, with the idea that a sum of an empty array is zero (and `has_sum(nonzero, [])` should return false); for a larger array, we pop off its head, and see if the sum of the rest of the array is okay if we count, or don't count, the head element. Here, we don't do the useless summing of the whole array over and over again:

```
def has_sum?(val, arr)
  if arr.empty?
    val.zero?
  else
    first, *rest = arr
    has_sum?(val, rest) || has_sum?(val - first, rest)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't believe you need `to_a`.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, so I suppose the `combination` keyword there outputs every possible combination items can have within an array?  Is `i + 1` there needed?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Tried without `to_a`? I did. `combination` returns an `Enumerator`, which `flat_map` does not unpack.

Comment: `combination` outputs all subsets of given size. I want to test all sizes from 1 to N; `times` gives me numbers from 0 to N-1. That said... It would be better to test from 0 to N, so that it returns the same result as the second example (true for `has_sum?(0, [])`); so I moved the `+1` :)

Comment: Ah, yes, `flat_map`. In that case consider `(1..arr.size).any? { |i| combination(i).any? { |a| { |s| s.inject(:+) == val } }`, which I believe would be more efficient as it could terminate earlier.

Comment: Yeah... then I need nested `.any?`. I guess I could write that one out too, for completeness sake...

Comment: Also worth noting, an exception is thrown in the recursive example on `arr.empty?` when passing in an array of ints, I used `arr.size < 1` instead to fix it.

Comment: @jewnbug97: The recursive example, for me, returns the same results for the four test cases above. Can you specify which specific test case throws an error for you?

Answer (score 1):

This solution employs dynamic programming. I assume that zeroes have been removed from the array. If all numbers in the array are positive, we can also remove elements that are larger than the target sum.

**Code**

```
def sum_to_target(arr, target)
  h = arr.each_index.with_object({}) do |i,h|
    v = arr[i]
    h.keys.each do |n|
      unless h.key?(n+v) # || (n+v > target)
        h[n+v] = v
        return reconstruct(h, target) if n+v == target
      end
    end
    h[v] = v unless h.key?(v)
    return reconstruct(h, target) if v == target
  end
  nil
end

def reconstruct(h, target)
  a = []
  loop do
    i = h[target]
    a.unshift i
    target -= i
    return a if target == 0
   end
  a
end
```

Additional efficiency improvements are possible if `arr` contains only postive values.<sup>1</sup>

**Examples**

*#1*

```
sum_to_target [2,4,7,2], 8
  #=> [2, 4, 2]
```

*#2*

```
arr = [64, 18, 64, 6, 39, 51, 87, 62, 78, 62, 49, 86, 35, 57, 40, 15, 74, 10, 8, 7]
a = sum_to_target(arr, 461)
  #=> [64, 18, 39, 51, 87, 62, 78, 62]
```

Let's check that.

```
a.reduce(:+)
  #=> 461
```

*#3*

```
a = sum_to_target([-64, 18, 64, -6, 39, 51, -87, 62, -78, 62, 49, 86, 35, 57, 
                    40, 15, -74, 10, -8, -7], 190)
  #=> [18, 64, -6, 39, 51, -87, 62, 49] 

a.reduce(:+)
  #=> 190
```

*#4*

```
arr = 1_000.times.map { rand 1..5_000 }
  #=> [3471, 1891, 4257, 2265, 832, 1060, 3961, 875, 614, 2308, 2240, 3286,
  #    ...
  #    521, 1316, 1986, 4099, 1398, 3803, 4498, 4607, 2262, 3941, 4367]
```

`arr` is an array of 1,000 elements, each a random number between 1 and 5,000.

```
answer = arr.sample(500)
  #=> [3469, 2957, 1542, 950, 4765, 3126, 3602, 755, 4132, 4281, 2374,
  #    ...
  #    427, 4238, 4397, 2717, 912, 1690, 3626, 169, 3607, 4084, 3161]
```

`answer` is an array of 500 elements from `arr`, sampled without replacement.

```
target = answer.reduce(:+)
  #=> 1_226_020
```

`target` is the sum of the elements of `answer`. We will now search `arr` for a collection of elements that sum to `1,226,020` (`answer` being one such collection).

```
require 'time'
t = Time.now
  #=> 2016-12-12 23:00:51 -0800 

a = sum_to_target(arr, target)
  #=> [3471, 1891, 4257, 2265, 832, 1060, 3961, 875, 614, 2308, 2240, 3286,
  #    ...
  #    3616, 4150, 3222, 3896, 631, 2806, 1932, 3244, 2430, 1443, 1452]
```

Notice that `a != answer` (which is not surprising).

```
a.reduce(:+)
  #=> 1226020 

(Time.now-t).to_i
  #=> 60 seconds
```

For this last example, methods that use [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) would have to wade though as many as

```
(1..arr.size).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + arr.combination(i).size }.to_f
  #~> 1.07+301
```

combinations.

**Explanation**

Let

```
arr = [2,4,7,2]
target = 8
```

Suppose we temporarily redefine `reconstruct` to return the hash passed to it.

```
def reconstruct(h, target)
  h
end
```

We then obtain the following:

```
h = sum_to_target(arr, target)
  #=> {2=>2, 6=>4, 4=>4, 9=>7, 13=>7, 11=>7, 7=>7, 8=>2}
```

`h` is defined as follows.

*Given an array of non-zero integers `arr` and a number `n`, if `n` is a key of `h` there exists an array `a` containing elements from `arr`, in the same order, such that the elements of `a` sum to `n` and the last element of `a` equals `h[n]`.*

which, admittedly, is a mouthful.

We now use the `reconstruct` (as defined in the "Code" section) to construct an array `answer` that will contain elements from `arr` (without repeating elements) that sum to `target`.

```
reconstruct(h, target) #=> [2, 4, 2]
```

Initially, `reconstruct` initializes the array `answer`, which it will build and return:

```
answer = []
```

`h` will always contain a key equal to target (`8`). As `h[8] #=> 2` we conclude that the last element of `answer` equals `2`, so we execute

```
answer.unshift(2) #=> [2]
```

The problem is now to find an array of elements from `arr` that sum to `8 - 2 #=> 6`. As `h[6] #=> 4`, we conclude that the element in `answer` that precedes the `2` we just added is `4`:

```
answer.unshift(4) #=> [4, 2]
```

We now need `8-2-4 #=> 2` more to total `target`. As `h[2] #=> 2` we execute

```
answer.unshift(2) #=> [2, 4, 2]
```

Since `8-2-4-2 #=> 0` we are finished and therefore return `answer`.

Notice that `4` precedes the last `2` in `arr` and the first `2` precedes the `4` in `arr`. The way `h` is constructed ensures the elements of `answer` will always be ordered in this way.

Now consider how `h` is constructed. First,

```
h = {}
```

As `arr[0] #=> 2`, we conclude that, using only the first element of `arr`, all we can conclude is:

```
h[2] = 2
h #=> {2=>2}
```

`h` has no key equal to `target` (`8`), so we continue. Now consider `arr[1] #=> 4`. Using only the first two elements of `arr` we can conclude the following:

```
h[2+4] = 4
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>4}
```

and since `h` has no key `4`,

```
h[4]   = 4
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>4, 4=>4}
```

`h` still has no key equal to `target` (`8`), so we press on and examine `arr[2] #=> 7`. Using only the first three elements of `arr` we conclude the following:

```
h[2+7] = 7
h[6+7] = 7
h[4+7] = 7
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>4, 4=>4, 9=>7, 13=>7, 11=>7}
```

and since `h` has no key `7`:

```
h[7]   = 7
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>4, 4=>4, 9=>7, 13=>7, 11=>7, 7=>7}
```

We added four elements to `h`, but since `arr` contains only positive numbers, those with keys `9`, `13` and `11` are of no interest.

Since `h` still does not have a key equal to `target` (`8`), we examine the next element in `arr`: `arr[3] #=> 2`. Using only the first four elements of `arr` we conclude the following:

```
h[4+2]  = 2
h[6+2]  = 2
```

Here we stop, since `6+2 == target #=> true`.

```
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>2, 4=>4, 9=>7, 13=>7, 11=>7, 7=>7, 8=>2}
```

Notice that we did not compute `h[2+2] = 2` since `h` already has a key `4`. Further, had `arr` contained additional elements we still would have terminated the construction of the hash at this point.

Had we modified the code to take advantage of the fact that `arr` contains only positive values, the final hash would have been:

```
h #=> {2=>2, 6=>2, 4=>4, 7=>7, 8=>2}
```

If this is still not clear, it might be helpful to run the code for this example with included `puts` statements (e.g., `puts "i=#{i}, h=#{h}, v=#{v}"` after the line `v = arr[i]` in `sum_to_target`, and so on).

<sup>1 The line `unless h.key?(n+v)` can be changed to `unless h.key?(n+v) || (n+v > target)` if it is known that the array contains no negative elements. (Doing so reduced the solution time for example #4 by 4 seconds.) One could also compute `@all_positive = arr.all?(&:positive?)` and then make that line conditional on `@all_positive`.</sup>

Comment: Great explanation.  I'll definitely be bookmarking this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would do nested loops.

```
for x = 0 to length of array
    for y = x + 1 to length of array
        if number at x + number at y = sum return true

return false
```

Basically it will check the sum of each number with each of the numbers after it.

EDIT: this will only sum 2 numbers at a time. If you want to be able to sum any amount of numbers this wont work.

Comment: Yes this is an implementation I thought about, but it's specifically wanting you to be able to sum any amount of numbers.  Thanks for this though.